# Constructing a neural network which intersects the function $f(x) = x^2$ more than $n$ times in the interval $[0, b]$

Tags: neural-networks

Given constants $b, n ∈ N$, provide a neural network which implements a function $g_{b,n} : R → R$ such that
$|{x ∈ R : g_{b,n}(x) = x^2, 0 ≤ x ≤ b}| > n$,
i.e., $g_{b,n}$ intersects the function $f(x) = x^2$ more than $n$ times in the interval $[0, b]$.

My idea is to create a zig zag sort of function split into $b/n$ parts where the start and the end points of each part are at $y=0$ and the midpoint of each part is at $y = b^2$. This ensures that there are 2 intersections in each part.

I know how to create a neural network which makes a linear function, but I'm unsure how to make a zigzag function like this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I like your suggestion for it's simplicity; the network could just learn 2(b/n) + 1 points, and then you can linearly interpolate from there.

Another idea is to create a network to approximate the function $f(x) = x^2(\sin(\frac{2\pi n x}{b}))$.  Note that over $[0,b]$, defining $g(x) = \sin(\frac{2\pi n x}{b})$, we have $|g^{-1}(1)| = n$, which implies $f(x) = x^2$ exactly $n$ times.

If you are concerned that a tangental intersection might not be a strong enough condition, you could always consider $\sin(\frac{2\pi n x}{b}) + 1$ instead.

Here is a simple script in pytorch that creates and trains such a network:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(2, 64)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


def generate_data(n, b):
    x = np.linspace(0, b, 100)
    y = np.power(x, 2) * (np.sin((2 * np.pi * n * x) / b) + 1)
    return y

input_data = []
target_data = []
for n in range(1, 20):
    for b in np.linspace(1,2,11):
        input_data.append([n,b])
        target_data.append(generate_data(n,b))

input_data = torch.tensor(input_data, dtype=torch.float32)
target_data = torch.tensor(target_data, dtype=torch.float32)

train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(input_data,target_data)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

model = Net()
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(1000):
    for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_func(outputs, targets)
        
        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

And for $n=2$ and $b=2$, the trained network outputs
[image]